# What are MinGW Repository Catalogues?

Tags: repository, mingw

In the MinGW installer there was mention of Repository Catalogues. Does that mean that MinGW has a repository system like `apt-get`?

I am referring to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found `mingw-get`, and it works exactly like `apt-get`, and the Repository Catalogues are used by it.